# Defining a new type of floating environment

Tags: floats, environments

In a document, I need to provide some details about specific topics without disrupting the flow of the main document, so that the details may easily be omitted at first reading. To do so, I thought it would be convenient to write the corresponding paragraphs in a frame outside the body of the document. This can be done easily using, for instance, `mdframed`, and I can wrap the commands defining the frame into a `\newenvironment`.

However, I feel that the general layout of the document would be much nicer if the frames were allowed to float and could be numbered and referred to in the main body of the document exactly like figures are. Is there a simple way to create such a floating environment?

So far, the solution I have found is to hijack the `figure` environment using a new counter, and to redefine the command `\theHfigure` locally so that hyperlinks built by `hyperref` point to the right location.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{framecnt}
\newenvironment{frameenv}[1]
    {\begin{figure}[tb]
    \refstepcounter{framecnt}
    \renewcommand{\theHfigure}{cont.\arabic{framecnt}}
    \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=blue!10]
    \textbf{\centerline{Frame \arabic{framecnt} --- #1}}
    \smallskip

    \begin{multicols*}{2}
    }
    {\end{multicols*}\end{mdframed}\end{figure}
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{frameenv}{More details}\label{frame1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frameenv}

See frame \ref{frame1} or figure \ref{fig1}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{A real figure}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the output it generates:
[image]

Does a more "natural" solution exist?

Comment: ...make your *own* floating environment with the aid of the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: Why not use a 'tcolorbox' environment that can simplyb be made floating and auto-numbered and provides a lot of other very powerful features ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a few packages that can help with this- personally I would choose the [`newfloat`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/newfloat) package because it is from the same author as the excellent [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package, which means that the two packages work *very* well together.

Below is a mock up of your original code, but using these two packages; the important lines are

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Frame]{myfloat}
\captionsetup[myfloat]{labelfont=bf}
```

which sets up a new floating environment- it also creates `\jobname.frm` which contains information that will be useful if you want to create a list of your frames, using the command

```
\listofmyfloats
```

which the `newfloat` package created for us.

I also moved the `hyperref` package to be loaded *last*; this is important, as discussed in [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Frame]{myfloat}

\captionsetup[myfloat]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newenvironment{frameenv}[1]
    {\begin{myfloat}[tb]
    \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=blue!10]
    \caption{#1}
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
    }
    {\end{multicols*}\end{mdframed}\end{myfloat}
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{frameenv}{More details}\label{frame1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frameenv}

See frame \ref{frame1} or figure \ref{fig1}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{A real figure}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Another thought is to make the argument to your environment optional so that you can have an empty `caption`. This is easily done, using

```
\newenvironment{frameenv}[1][]
     {\begin{myfloat}[tb]
     ...
```

which means that you use, noting the square brackets and not braces,

```
\begin{frameenv}[Details for the caption]\label{frame1}
```

or

```
\begin{frameenv}\label{frame2}
```

You could also remove the `caption` from the definition of the environment and specify it manually each time, but that's up to you.