# Exchange number against letter in figure caption

Tags: numbering, captions, letters

I have a lot of figures which are numbered with: Figure 1.1, ..., Figure 8.5.
In between, I have two special figures, that I want to call Figure A and B, so that the numbering of figues goes like:

Figure 1.1, ..., Figure 2.2, Figure A, Figure 2.3, ... Figure 5.6, Figure B, Figure 6.1, ...

I have tried to play with the caption package, but did not find the command. Is there something like:

```
\documentclass{ThesisTemplate}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.\linewidth]{./figs/special_figure}
\captionsetup{letter="A"}
\caption{Description of special figure}
\label{fig:special}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How should the numbering  of the figures continue after thie "special figure"? Could you please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: You probably should declare a new float, numbered alphabetically.

Comment: @Bernard How do I do that?

Comment: @leandriis Thank you, I've edited the post.

Comment: See this answer for declaring a new float https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95634/24974

Comment: Load the `float` package and use something like `\newfloat{Afigure}{htbp}{loa}[chapter]` in the preamble: `htbp` are the possible placements for the new float (like the standard figure), `loa` is the extension for the auxiliary file that LaTeX would use to construct the list of Afigures, and the optional `[chapter]` would mean the ‘numbering’ would restart at each chapter.