# Floating environment with caption outside the box

Tags: floats, captions, environments, mdframed, newfloat

I have defined a float environment following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95634/195626) in the "optional caption" version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Frame]{myfloat}

\captionsetup[myfloat]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newenvironment{frameenv}[1][]
{\begin{myfloat}[tb]
        \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=blue!10]
        \caption{#1}
        }
        {\end{mdframed}\end{myfloat}
}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{frameenv}[Details for the caption]\label{frame1}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{frameenv}

    See frame \ref{frame1}.

\end{document}
```

Now I want to move the caption outside the box, so I tried moving the `\caption{#1]` command in the `{enddef}` argument of `\newenvironment{}` between `\end{mdframed}` and `\end{myfloat}`, changing the definition of the `frameenv` environment to the following:

```
\newenvironment{frameenv}[1][]
{\begin{myfloat}[tb]
        \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=blue!10]
        }
        {\end{mdframed}\caption{#1}\end{myfloat}
}
```

When I compile the document I get an error:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \endframeenv.
>
> 1
>
> l.16 }

and I can't figure out where is my mistake.

How can I move the caption outside the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to smuggle `#1` to the second part using `\def\mycaption{#1}` and then `\expandafter\caption{\expandafter\mycaption}` in the end. Big thanks to Axel Sommerfeldt for pointing out the `\expandafter`s and, in particular, wha they are good for!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Frame]{myfloat}

\captionsetup[myfloat]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newenvironment{frameenv}[1][]
{\def\mycaption{#1}\begin{myfloat}[tb]
        \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=blue!10]
        }
        {\end{mdframed}\expandafter\caption{\expandafter\mycaption}\end{myfloat}
}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{frameenv}[Details for the caption\label{frame1}]
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{frameenv}

    See frame \ref{frame1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{frameenv}[\label{frame1}]` will produce "Frame 1:". To get rid of the colon automatically in this case (empty caption text), replace `\caption{\mycaption}` with `\expandafter\caption\expandafter{\mycaption}`.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks! I will be happy to remove this. It is much more appropriate if you write an answer.

Comment: It's not clear to me my I should write my own answer. Your answer is fine and my comment is just a little improvement of your answer (by adding two `\expandafter`), so the "drop separator if caption text is empty" algorithm of the `caption` package will remain intact.