# Create list of charts

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents

I have some problems creating a list for frame. I have a table and a frame and I want to create a list for both.

With \ begin {table}, I can use captioning to create a table list, but I can't do it on the chart either because I'm using the caption * {frame}

Here is an example:

```
\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newpage

\textual

%TABLE 1
%\parbox{7cm}{\
\begin{table}[H]\footnotesize
  \centering
    \parbox{15.5cm}{\caption{Distribuição das receitas médias municipais e estaduais de acordo com as Grandes Regiões do Brasil, 1985-2015, por porcentagem}\label{tab01}}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}
    \begin{tabular}{rccccc|ccccc}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Receita Tributária}      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Transferências Correntes} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{MUNICÍPIOS} & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 \\
    \midrule
    Brasil & 11.37 & 22.66 & 18.08 & 18.07 & 19.48 & 60.26 & 60.92 & 65.67 & 66.86 & 64.13 \\
    Centro-Oeste & 9.53  & 24.84 & 12.11 & 12.98 & 15.71 & 66.83 & 75.12 & 74.28 & 72.31 & 71.90 \\
    Nordeste & 6.90  & 12.12 & 9.54  & 9.68  & 18.05 & 60.56 & 79.25 & 79.27 & 80.74 & 84.70 \\
    Norte & 5.80  & 13.27 & 9.35  & 10.33 & 31.69 & 56.73 & 76.73 & 77.45 & 79.05 & 86.47 \\
    Sudeste & 22.04 & 26.43 & 23.81 & 23.84 & 19.75 & 50.59 & 52.64 & 58.44 & 59.42 & 49.62 \\
    Sul & 12.57 & 19.86 & 15.19 & 15.41 & 17.40 & 66.57 & 67.31 & 65.41 & 65.88 & 71.21 \\
    \midrule
    ESTADOS & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 & 85-94 & 95-99 & 00-04 & 05-09 & 10-15 \\
    \midrule
    Brasil & 79.14 & 65.59 & 63.35 & 62.34 & 61.91 & 18.66 & 24.22 & 22.31 & 24.53 & 22.43 \\
    Centro-Oeste & 59.79 & 50.11 & 58.70 & 62.58 & 58.44 & 31.08 & 40.97 & 27.74 & 22.75 & 20.98 \\
    Nordeste & 56.38 & 50.25 & 47.28 & 45.79 & 48.49 & 34.64 & 43.69 & 39.48 & 43.19 & 40.26 \\
    Norte & 45.18 & 42.68 & 41.85 & 41.15 & 41.61 & 62.08 & 49.87 & 48.53 & 48.87 & 44.35 \\
    Sudeste & 82.70 & 77.23 & 72.10 & 71.02 & 70.09 & 9.07  & 13.13 & 11.95 & 13.99 & 11.94 \\
    Sul & 84.69 & 62.59 & 67.33 & 67.21 & 68.29 & 10.50 & 18.34 & 19.61 & 22.35 & 19.90 \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Fonte: Elaboração própria com base em dados da Secretaria do Tesouro Nacional.}}
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{flushleft}
    \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{table}%

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'fpm'
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption*{Quadro 1 - Coeficientes do FPM interior por faixa de habitantes.}
  \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{p{10.785em}lrr}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .839,  .89,  .737} \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{Faixa de habitantes} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{10.085em}|}{Faixa de habitantes} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{Até 10.188} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.6} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 61.129 a 71.316} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.4} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 10.189 a 13.584} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.8} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 71.317 a 81.504} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.6} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 13.585 a 16.980} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.0} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 81.505 a 91.692} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.8} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 16.981 a 23.772} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 91.693 a 101.880} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.0} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 23.773 a 30.564} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.4} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 101.881 a 115.464} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.2} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 30.565 a 37.356} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.6} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 115.465 a 129.048} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.4} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 37.357 a 44.148} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.8} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 129.049 a 142.632} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.6} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 44.149 a 50.940} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.0} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{De 142.633 a 156.216} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.8} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.835em}|}{De 50.941 a 61.128} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{10.085em}|}{Acima de 156.216} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4.0} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{p{30.42em}}{Fonte: Decreto Lei nº 1.881/1981.} \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab02}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Other example is that I want separate figure and graphs for a list too.

That's possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also edit your example code to match your question. You state " I have a table and a frame" but your code only contains two tables. Where is your "frame"? Regarding: "I want separate figure and graphs for a list too": Please also add an example for a "figre"  and for a "graph".

Comment: Completely unrelated, but pleae keep in mind that the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package are incompatible with vertical lines.

Comment: I cannot make a graph because I don't know any command that is " \begin{graph} " for example, I only know "\begin{figure} ". I have "\begin{table} " but I cannot have command for frame (or chart)

Comment: In order to create a new float type such as `table` of `figure` but for something different, I'd recommend the `newfloat` packages. See also [Defining a new type of floating environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95634/134144)

Comment: Ok, It's works create a new float. The second part is: How can I create a list of this float?

Comment: With the `\listof...` command with `...` begin the name of the newly created float.

Comment: I use: \newfloat{grafico}{tbp}{ext} | 
\floatname{grafico}{Gráfico} to create new float ... So I need only add \listofgrafico ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks leandriss.

I use newfloat to create my chart and graph and use this for create my list of charts and graphs

```
\newfloat{quadro}{tbhp}{crt}
\floatname{quadro}{Quadro}

\newfloat{grafico}{tbp}{ext}
\floatname{grafico}{Gráfico}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Quadro}
\listof{quadro}{Lista de Quadros}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Gráfico}
\listof{grafico}{Lista de Gráficos}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a MWE for your answer that seems super useful!