# How to make minipage float like a figure?

Tags: floats, minipage

Is there a way to place minipages the same way like figures position them automatically? 
My minipages always break my text. I want to put them to the top of the page but this doesnt work with [t]. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that problem?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Maybe put it in a figure environment without a caption.

Comment: This could be helpful: [Defining a new type of floating environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95634/97512)