# How to make a document with figures and schemes

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, overleaf, renewcommand

First at all, sorry for my english, im colombian.

Im a Chemistry student, in my thesis I need put in that two types of images, "figures" and "schemes", and their respect `\listof...` when i tried to change the figurename i always change the figurename of both.
I tried to make a `\newcommand[]` to make schemes but its based in `\begin{figure}` so, change the figurename of all the document.

Comment: Welcome! There is a package for this --- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat . It has exactly your example in the manual, with *diagrams* instead of *schemes* ;-)

Comment: Could be https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95631/defining-a-new-type-of-floating-environment a duplicate of this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [float](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) package with its macro `\newfloat` to create a custom float. Alternatively, you could try [toclotf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) but the latter is more complex. In both cases, you might also consider [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), which helps to customise references to your new and existing counters.

Here's one possible solution:

[image]

PS. I am not sure if `Schema/Schemata` is what you are up to as well as which of the form of Schemas/Schemata is correct but I think you should take on from here.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{schema}{tbh}{sch}
\floatname{schema}{Schema}
\floatplacement{figure}{tbh}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\listof{schema}{List of Schemata}

\clearpage
Figure \ref{fig:label1}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Short figure caption]{Very long long caption under the figure}
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

Schema \ref{sch:label1}

\begin{schema}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{1.2cm}
    \caption[Short schema caption]{Very very long caption under the schema}
    \label{sch:label1}
\end{schema}

Figure \ref{fig:label2}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Short figure caption]{Very long long caption under the figure}
    \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure}

Schema \ref{sch:label2}

\begin{schema}[!tbh]
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{1.2cm}
    \caption[Short schema caption]{Very very long caption under the schema}
    \label{sch:label2}
\end{schema}
\end{document}
```